# Java - LinkedList : Weird NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I have a little problem with a NullPointerException that I can't really understand.

My code runs 24/7 and works pretty well but I have that exception that pops randomly from 1 day to 1 week after the application is started.

Here is the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:477)
at com.ch4process.acquisition.ScenarioWorker.eventHandling(ScenarioWorker.java:97)
at com.ch4process.acquisition.ScenarioWorker.call(ScenarioWorker.java:79)
at com.ch4process.acquisition.ScenarioWorker.call(ScenarioWorker.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

As you can see this exception is rised in a thread.

Here is the code (simplified a bit) :

```
public class ScenarioWorker implement Callable<Integer>
{
List<SignalValueEvent> eventList = new LinkedList<>();

boolean busy = false;

@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            eventHandling();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Redirects the exception to a custom class
    }
}

private void eventHandling()
{
    if (! busy)
    {
        while (eventList.size() > 0)
        {       
            SignalValueEvent event = eventList.get(0); // NullPointerException here according to stacktrace

            if(event.isTriggered()))
            {
                busy = true;
                doScenario(event);
            }
            deleteEvent();
        }
    }
}


private void deleteEvent()
{
    try
    {
        eventList.remove(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Redirects the exception to custom class
    }
    finally
    {
        busy = false;
    }
}


@Override
public void SignalValueChanged(SignalValueEvent event)
{
    if (event.isValid())
    {
        eventList.add(event);
    }
}
```

}

[Edit : the line 97 in the stacktrace is the line saying SignalValueEvent event = eventList.get(0); ]

This class implements an interface which allows another class to notify it by calling the SignalValueChanged method.

So basically my LinkedList is created at the initialization of the class, filled by an external class whenever an event needs to be put in the list, and the call method loops on the list to see if there's anything in it. If there is, it's treated and the event is deleted.

I've tested this and the only reason I should have a NPException is if my list is equal to null... but I don't do that anywhere in my code...

As I said this code is working 24/7 and I had this bug almost one week and a half after I started the application. Is it something obvious I am missing ?

Thank you so much for reading this and if you can help me I'll be glad :)

Comment: 1) Which line is line 97? `ScenarioWorker.java:97` 2) Is the code failing at every run now, or intermittently? 3) If intermittently, then this suggests a concurrency problem. Are you sure that your code is thread safe?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : The line 97 is SignalValueEvent event = eventList.get(0); I will edit my post to reflect that.

The problem is intermitent, and I thought that LinkedList was thread safe ?..

Comment: I think also that this is a concurrency problem, because of irregular failing

Comment: `"I thought that LinkedList was thread safe"` -- this is **very** dangerous and incorrect thinking! Yes, this is likely the cause of your problems.

Comment: "Java Concurrency in Practice" https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/0321349601/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1483365378&sr=1-1&keywords=java+concurrency+in+practice - get hold of this book and study it at great length.  If you don't you will be living in a world of pain forever.

Comment: This is a good example of why most event handling systems use a single thread to process the event queue.

Comment: I get it, concurrency issue ok. But no other thread have access to this LinkedList.

Comment: Then it's probably similar to a ConcurrentModificationException type event: read the book!

Comment: Note that the NPE isn't because your list is null -- if it were, the root of your exception would be on ScenarioWorker.java line 97. Instead the code is making it into the internals of LinkedList, which indicates that something internal to the LinkedList implementation is getting screwed up -- a huge red flag for concurrency problems. As for why, probably a race in one thread calling SignalValueChanged and another calling eventHandling at the same time.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I'm pretty new to Java as you can guess but I thought that thread-safety was an issue when multiple threads were using a common resource. In my case the LinkedList is not used by any other thread. Just by this one thread creating it and using it.

Is thread-safety an issue in this case ?

Comment: Yes, yes, and Y.E.S.

Comment: @jacobm: your latest comment is better than any of the posted answers. Please make that an answer so that it can be accepted by the original poster.

Comment: @KevinEsche: this is most definitely not a duplicate of the question you've posted as the NPE has nothing to do with a variable being null but rather a concurrency issue. The usual techniques of NPE debugging will not work here. Please see jacobm's comment to see why.

Comment: @jacobm I second what Hovercraft says about you making an answer.  I just also checked the source for LinkedList.get (Java 8 - 091), l. 477 as per trace - and this shows that the checkElementIndex check passed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers guys. I don't recall where I read that LinkedList was thread-safe but I used them because of that... so now I know that they are NOT thread-safe and will use something else like a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

I feel like an idiot but at least I learned something today.

I'm waiting on jacobm to make his comment as an answer to accept it.

Comment: @Caerbannog Sorry to be an old bore but that is not the best lesson to draw from this discussion. LinkedList can in fact be used from multiple threads (see the Javadoc) but the main problem I have with you just switching classes is that your understanding of concurrency needs to be improved.  I'm saying this for your own good: concurrency makes the proudest of us humble.

Comment: Caerbannog (Welsh name?), for what it's worth, I'm also thinking of getting the book that @mikerodent recommends since concurrency is a hairy subject and is one of the most difficult aspects of Java or any programming language.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels From your answers (and your rep) I was pretty much sure you had already read it (studied it). One word of advice: check out the online errata page! They may have produced a corrected edition, but in the one I read there were errata in the code which as you might imagine made an already challenging subject far worse.

Comment: @mikerodent Don't worry, I'm not just switching classes and forgetting about this problem. I will patch my code and study this book so that this kind of situation won't be problematic in the future.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NPE isn't because your list is null -- if it were, the root of your exception would be on `ScenarioWorker.java` line 97. Instead the code is making it into the internals of `LinkedList`, which indicates that something internal to the `LinkedList` implementation is getting screwed up -- a huge red flag for concurrency problems. As for why, probably a race in one thread calling `SignalValueChanged` and another calling `eventHandling` at the same time.

You can solve it by synchronizing all access to `eventList`. The easiest way is probably just to mark the methods `SignalValueChanged` and `eventHandling` as `synchronized`.

Comment: Yup... well spotted.  And as I mentioned, line 477 (stack trace) also shows (if you look at the source for LinkedList, Java 8, _091) that the "index check" passed... i.e. it is not a question of an out-of-bounds due to an empty list (which would give a different Exception anyway, of course).

Answer (score 3):

I think this is related to threads synchronization too. Solution:  Encapsulate `eventList` in an object with `synchronized` methods. Access `eventList` from all threads by calling these synchronized methods only.

Answer (score 2):

Just read [`LinkedList`s JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:
>
> `List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...));`

Answer (score 1):

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggests above, I'm guessing that this is a concurrency issue.

Most likely, at the time that you're calling `eventList.get(0)`, despite having "just" tested that the list is not empty, either the list became null or the list became empty, via another concurrent thread.

Edit: As discussed in the comments to the question, the NullPointerException is being thrown from the inner workings of LinkedList, meaning it's most definitely a concurrency issue.

Make your objects thread-safe, and you will solve the problem.

Comment: I should have an IndexOutOfBound exception if the list is empty, not a NullPointerException. And I never ever destroy that list or set it to null so I don't know why it would be that way.

Comment: @Caerbannog Except that you are using a `LinkedList` not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, strictly speaking @Caerbannog is correct. LinkedList also throws an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get(int)

Which means that the NPE is more likely to be due to the list itself being set to null, but that's unclear why it would happen. If possible, I'd add a test for a null list there to see if that condition flips in runtime. I still suspect concurrency.

Comment: No! As jacobm points out in the other comments, the Exception is being thrown by the internals of LinkedList, not by eventList.get(...)!!!